# Linear reverse search python

Tags: python, list, function, reverse, linear-search

How can I rewrite the function below to search from the end of the list?

```
def search(list,n): 
  
    for i in range(len(list)): 
        if list[i] == n: 
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: why dont you use `list.reverse()`

Comment: @Evorage where exactly do I have to use this?

Comment: 0 isn't in the list, what do you expect to find?

Comment: @Sayse this have to return False obviously. You can replace 0 with any number in the list and it still doesn't do what I want to.

Comment: This is actually working as you wish. The list itself is not reversed. The `reversed` function is allowing you to iterate over the range in a reversed order.

Comment: @Ant but how do I check if the list has been reversed?

Comment: The list hasn't been reversed though, you reversed the range. and it doesn't need to be reversed because reversing the range does exactly what reversing the list would do

Comment: **The linear search starts from index 0. How can I rewrite the function below to search from the end of the list instead of from the beginning?** your code exactly do this. It is absolutely right. `print(i)` to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate backwards through the list. For that you need to specify your range with three parameters. The first would be the starting point, the second the endpoint, and the third would be the increment. That's better than reversing it in runtime matters. Try this:

```
def search(list, n):
   for i in range(len(list)-1, 0, -1):
      print(list)
      if list[i]=n:
        return True
   return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.reverse()` to reverse your list so that you are starting from the end:

```
list= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n=(3)
list.reverse()

def search(list,n): 
  
    for i in reversed(range(len(list))): 
        print(list)
        if list[i] == n: 
            return True
    return False
search(list,n)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to do this inside of the function. these list and n variables are just an example to show what I get when I run the function.

Comment: Why do you need it inside the function? When you define your list, isn't it outside your function? Just reverse it right after you define it.

Comment: I want this function to work on any list, not for this specific one. And when I use a list as an argument I want it to be reversed inside of the function so I do not reverse every single list I create.

Comment: then just use: nameofyourlist.reverse()  on whatever list you want, and move it inside the function