# Python - backwards iteration through range in list

Tags: python, range

I'd like to search backwards through a list

This is code that I read in other posts should work

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(ls)-1, 0, -1):
    print(i)
```

The output would be:

```
2
1
```

Wheras if I use this code:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(ls)-1, -1, -1):
    print(i)
```

The output is:

```
2
1
0
```

Why is it that `range(len(ls)-1, 0, -1)` skips an element, and why is it recommended as a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127658/linear-reverse-search-python) for backwards iteration (rather than `range(len(ls)-1, -1, -1)`)?

Comment: The stop index (second argument to `range`) is exclusive. Iteration stops __before__ that index.

Comment: Since you say you want to search through the list I assume you're interested in the list values. In that case you don't need the index at all. A simple `for value in reversed(ls):` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the index being negative, you can do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for i in range(-1, -1*(len(a)+1), -1):
    print(i, a[i])
```